# Average result for brms conditional effects in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, emmeans, brms

I'm using conditional_effects from the library brms and I saw that emmeans average the result over the levels of different factor when conditional_effects select the first one.

So, how could I do the same thing with conditional effects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your code so I don't know what t hose factors are. But if you want to condition on a factor, just include it in the specs, say as a by variable. e.g.,

```
emmeans(model, ~ treatment | dose)
```

Or if you want only one level of `dose`, specify it in `at`:

```
emmeans(model, ~ treatment, at = list(dose = 50))
```